# Can't Fetch Laravel API Data on Heroku

Tags: laravel, api, heroku, deployment

I have a Laravel REST API deployed on a free Heroku server. I also have the ClearDB MySQL extension installed on the deployed app.

My issue is that when I type in my URL in Postman to find my API data, I get this error message embedded in some HTML:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'ip' (using password: YES) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `test_data`)
```

So, it's the right URL, but for some reason, I'm not permitted to access it.

I've also tried to migrate my local database data to my deployed db but I get the following error message:

```
In Connection.php line 665:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'ip' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * fro  
  m information_schema.tables where table_schema = heroku_xxxxx and table_name = migrations and table_type =   
  'BASE TABLE')                                                                                                          


In Connector.php line 70:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'user'@'ip' (using password: YES)
```

I understand that these are permission errors but I'm not sure why I'm getting them. I'm also aware that Heroku's infrastructure depends on Postgres and it may be easier to use that. But for now, at least, I already have a MySQL db so I want to use that. Hence, why I installed ClearDB, to use a MySQL db.

In my config vars on Heroku I only have this:

```
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL: (The URL)
```

Why am I getting these errors and How can I fetch and view my API data?

Comment: this looks like .env database misconfiguration. Are you sure you have the correct settings?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please edit your question and add the code in your `config/database.php`